# Is it bad practice to reference System.Web.Security in the model when using entity service/repository pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, refactoring

Throughout my ASP.net site i need to check if the logged in users belongs to a role or has a field in my "UserInstance" table in my database set to true. To do this i can do the following.

```
if(Roles.IsUserInRole("Global Admin") 
|| uow.UserInstanceService.GetUserInstance(userId,InstanceId).Admin)
{
 //Do something
}
```

However as i am going to be using this code a lot as much of the permissions depend on the logged in user either being a "Global Admin" or a field of my table being true I don't want to write this out constantly.

One solution i have found is to create a method in the "UserInstance" Service which checks for both as seen in the "IsUserAdminOrGlobalAdmin" method.

```
 public class UserInstanceService
{
    IRepository<UserInstance> userInstanceRepository;

    public UserInstanceService(IRepository<UserInstance> userInstanceRepository)
    {
        this.userInstanceRepository = userInstanceRepository;
    }

    public UserInstance GetByUserIdAndInstanceId(Guid userId, int instanceId)
    {
       return userInstanceRepository.GetSingle(u => u.UserId == userId && u.InstanceId == instanceId);
    }

   public bool IsUserAdminOrGlobalAdmin(Guid userId,int instanceId)
    {
        bool valid = false;

        if (System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole("Global Admin"))
            valid = true;

        if (GetByUserIdAndInstanceId(userId, instanceId).Admin)
            valid = true;

        return valid;
    } 
   //Removed rest of methods for readability
}
```

As this is buisness logic I put this method is in my "UserInstanceService" class which interacts with the repository class which contains the entity context. This service class resides in a seperate Model project so i had to add a reference to System.Web.Security and i am not sure if doing this is good practice. One thing i have noticed is that i can not write unit tests for this method as it relies on a user being logged in.

So my question is, is it acceptable to combine HttpContext specific functionality like the Logged in users roles, in a service?

**Edit** - After reading the answers I have changed my code so a Auth service (in the Web app project) is called which in turn calls the UserInstanceService to something like this.

```
public class Auth: IAuthService {

public bool IsUserAdminOrGlobalAdmin(Guid userId,int instanceId) {

    myEntities entityContext = new myEntities

    //RepsitoryBase inherits my IRepository<TEntity> class 
    UserInstanceService uis = new UserInstanceService(new RepositoryBase<UserInstance>(entityContext));
    bool valid = false

    if(Roles.IsUserInRole("Global Admin"))
         valid = true;

    if(uis.GetByUserIdAndInstanceId(userId,instanceId).Admin)
         valid = true;

    return valid;

}
```

}

So i could call this in my pages like this

```
if(Auth.IsUserAdminOrGlobalAdmin(userId,InstanceId)
{
//Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original answer was written assuming the UserAccess requires the Authentication, but it appears that the Authentication consumes the UserAccess; simply invert the dependencies, but everything else should be usable in about the same manner.

---

Original answer:

Pull the ASP.NET-specific code into it's *own* service separate from the repository. Then that service - say, the Auth Service - can be used by any component (such as the UserInstanceService) that needs access to centralized authentication/authorization logic.

[Consume the Auth as a *dependency* per IoC principles](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Services-and-Components.ashx), hopefully using some DI to make life easier.

If the Auth service is kept separate it can also be trivially mocked for testing, such as testing what happens when the use is authenticated or not, which entirely avoids the need to setup a full ASP.NET stack for the User service.

In addition, because services (interfaces) and components (classes) are separate, the actualy HTTP-utilizing component can live in a separate project from the service and wired in later - this will avoid pulling in Web dependencies to the Model project.

---

For example,

```
// This is the Service Contract and can live in the Model
public class IAuthService {
    void AssertCurrentUserIsAdminOrGlobalAdmin();
    void AssertIsUserAdminOrGlobalAdmin(Guid userId,int instanceId);
}    

// This is the Component, which provides the Service, and is part
// of the Web/HTTP-specific project. It is wired up via IoC/DI from
// the large context of the application.
public class Auth: IAuthService {
    public void AssertCurrentUserIsAdminOrGlobalAdmin() {
       // This one already knows the applicable HTTP/User Context
    }
    public void AssertIsUserAdminOrGlobalAdmin(Guid userId,int instanceId) {
       // Do whatever
    }
}

// This Component is part of the Model
public class UserInstanceService
{
    // IoC dependencies
    IRepository<UserInstance> userInstanceRepository;
    IAuthService authService;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think i understand, so you would recommend putting this in the Web app project and calling the "UserInstanceService" to check if the "Admin" field is true from the AuthService as well as the Roles.IsUserInRole("Global Admin")

Comment: Yes. The *component* (class, implementation of the service) lives in the Web-app project, but the *service* (interface, contract which defines the operations) lives in the Model itself - see http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Services-and-Components.ashx

Comment: Thanks again, I have made an edit which uses your code (Removed some for readability purposes) to show how i could implement it. However one thing i don't understand is why i would need the IAuthService in my "UserInstanceService" class as i assume i should never be calling the AuthService from my UserInstanceService class?

Comment: @user2945722 Oh, I see. So the Auth needs the HTTP-context *or* the UserRepository (not the way I originally had it, where I originally assumed it was required in the model for per-access checks). Simply invert the dependencies: Auth *consumes* HTTP (directly for ASP.NET roles) and UserInstanceService (for DB-managed roles). You can even keep pushing the dependencies up so that the Auth service knows the current user (i.e no need for userId/instanceId to be passed around). Also, might want to look into an ASP.NET security providers to avoid individual checks.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the current principal on the thread and use that instead. I think thats most of what ASP.Net does for you as well.